# VSCode Python with Git bash: After running program, tries to run Activate.ps1

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have the VSCode integrated terminal set to my Git bash, using this in settings.json:

```
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

I have the Python interpreter selected, using "Python: Select Interpreter" to the interpreter in my virtual environment - when I bring it up, it shows:
Current: C:\work_dir\projdir\py_env\venvdir\Scripts\python.exe

When go to the debugger and start the program (with or without debugging), the bash terminal opens, and this command is issued in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/env C:\\work_dir\\projdir\\py_env\\venvdir\\Scripts\\python.exe c:\\Users\\userid\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2020.9.111407\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\launcher 61892 -- c:\\work_dir\\projdir\\myscript.py -arg1 arg2
```

(where the args come from my launch.json)

Then, after the script finishes running, this command is issued in the terminal:

```
& C:/work_dir/projdir/py_env/venvdir/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

Which is the PowerShell way of activating the venv, I guess.
Which, of course, results in:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

The script actually runs fine.

Why is it that, after running the script in the bash terminal, VSCode issues a command in the terminal to try to activate the venv in a PowerShell way?
This is doubly weird: That it attempts a PowerShell command in a bash terminal, and that it attempts to activate the venv after and not before the script.

Answer (score 0):

The environment is activated automatically after .py file being executed unless you manually change the `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` setting to **false**.

More detailed information you can refer to [Environments and Terminal Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows)